# How to use AJAX and JSON to use in Django?

Tags: python, json, django

I am developing a search engine for our college using Django-Haystack-Solr. I want auto-suggestion and spell check feature. So I used `auto_query()` and `spelling_suggestion()` method.

This is my `views.py` file. As of now, it is only static script not taking any form input from actual user.

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from haystack.query import SearchQuerySet
import json
from django.http import HttpResponse

def testpage(request):
    search_keyword = 'stikar'
    data = SearchQuerySet().auto_query(search_keyword)
    spelling = data.spelling_suggestion()

    sqs = SearchQuerySet().autocomplete(context_auto=spelling)
    suggestions = [result.title for result in sqs]
    link = [result.url for result in sqs]
    context = [result.context for result in sqs]


    the_data = json.dumps({
        'results': suggestions,
        'link': link,
        'context': context
    })

    return HttpResponse(the_data, content_type='application/json')
```

My main `url.py` file:

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin
from search.views import testpage

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^test/', testpage),             # this is where JSON API is being generated
    url(r'^', include('haystack.urls')),  # this is where actual search page with search form is
]
```

I want that JSON response to be called whenever I go to that particular view. I want AJAX request to perform.

P.S: API is being rendered perfectly fine, no issues there. and sorry for bad English.

Please ask me for any extra information.

Thank you. :)

Answer (score 1):

Try using [jQuery autocomplete](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/) and call this api

Answer (score 0):

I have JSON format something like this:

```json
{
    'results': [suggestions],
    'link': [link],
    'context': [context]
}
```

This JSON comes from `/testpage/` and I want to use that in `/testquery/`. Here goes code for `testquery.html`

let assume that you want to perform a GET method with query param `q`.

```js
$.ajax({
    type:"GET",
    url:"/testpage/",
    data:{
        'q': <get param value from DOM>
    },
    success:function(data)
        {
            console.log(data.results);
            console.log(data.link);
            console.log(data.context);
        }
});
```